# What is the probability that that half of the women choose the supermarket 1 ? Combinatorial Analysis

Tags: probability, combinations

In a small town there are 3 supermarkets **(1,2,3)**. 4 Women decide to go shopping on the same day, and each one of them only choose 1 supermarket to go. Consider their choose are random and independent.

**What is the probability that half of the women choose the supermarket 1 ?**

I did: $$\frac{\binom 42\cdot\binom2 1\cdot\binom11}{3^4}$$

Can you tell me if this is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're off by a factor of 2. Yes, out of $3^4$ possibilities you have $4\choose2$ ways of picking the two women for supermarkt 1, but the two other women have each 2 options left, so you get ${2\choose1}^2$ possibilties for them. So you get:

$$\frac{{4\choose2}{2\choose1}^2}{3^4}$$

I think you assume that each supermarket needs to be frequented by at least 1 woman, but the way the question is phrased that need not be assumed. That is, 2 women can go to supermarket 1, and the other 2 to supermarket 2.

Comment: I understand you. But what I did in the numerator was: From a group of 4 women, I choose 2 to go to the supermarket 1, then I select 1 of 2 to the supermarket 2, and the last one to the supermarket 3

Comment: so it would be correct :\

Comment: @VitorAguiar If all 3 supermarkets need to be visited by at least 1 woman then you are absolutely correct! But the question does not stipulate that. So maybe no woman ends up going to supermarket 3. So then there are still two options for the 4th woman.

Comment: ohhhh, yes, you're right. Thanks

Comment: @VitorAguiar Hey, you got the formula spot on given your interpretation ... It was just the wrong interpretation :)

Comment: Now I did: binom42 * [binom21 + binom22 + binom22] . This way I am choosing the woman to the supermarket. But, I could do: binom42 * 2^2  ... This way, I am doing it faster, because I simply consider that there are still 2 options of supermarkets for the left 2 woman. If I had 100 supermarkets, this technique would be better.

Comment: @VitorAguiar If you have questions you should just create another post on the website!